# change uiviewcontroller without losing selection uiwebview

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have UIWebView in my present view. I need to change the font colour of the selected text. My colour pallete is on a another view controller. Im calling

[[[self window] rootViewController]presentViewController:colorController animated:YES completion:nil];

But when colour pallete displays UIWebView lost the selection.

Any idea how to solve this or set the selection again?

Answer (score 1):

Save the element that is touched in javascript before calling native methods from javascript. After choosing the color in native view, when you call the javascript method to change the color, your javascript code now will know what was selected before and you can go on accordingly.

Comment: Tried that does not work. 
    activeElement = [textView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getTextField(){ return document.activeElement.id; } getTextField();"];
    [textView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('%@').form.submit();", activeElement]];

Comment: what is happening? if you don't refresh inside uiwebview, all of the javascript memory should stay intact.

Comment: Do the opposite. Just pass the color value to UIWebView. Do not try to get the active element from the UIWebView.

Comment: im changing the view controller then i come back uiwebview lost the selection.

Comment: So you recreate the UIWebView... in that case store the UIWebView object and re-add it again instead of creating a new one. If you are using XIB files to add a UIWebView, do that programmatically in that case and again, retain the UIWebView.